# Can i use and is secure to use AJAX in my Server Node?

Tags: ajax, node.js, server

i would like to use native ajax to make some calls inside my node.js server.

Is this secure ?? Can i do it without problems ???

Here's and example:

```
.... NODE

app.post('/postReceptor', function(req, res, next) {

   var data1 = req.body['input1'];
   var data2 = req.body['input2'];

   var xhr;
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, ...
     xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
     try {
       xhr = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
     } 
     catch (e) {
       try {
         xhr = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
       } 
       catch (e) {}
     }
   }
   xhr.open('GET', encodeURI('HTTP://WWW.WEBSITE.COM'), true);
   xhr.send(null);
   xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {

       if(xhr.readyState === 4) { // done
         if(xhr.status === 200) { // complete   

             res.render('renderPage', { 
                sendingData: xhr.responseText
             });

         }
       }
    };
 });
```

This is to verify an external page some customer data sent by the client !

Thanks !

Comment: Well the statement "Is this secure ??", is far from being secure. First the user input is not validated, make sure you have error handling for the requests or otherwise the http response just hangs. Also as @Wilson Balderrama posted you are using the XHR browser API in server side use request.

Answer (score 1):

Doing AJAX calls is a concept that is originated from the client side and you are in the server so you don't have the `XMLHttpRequest` function available on Node.JS.

So to make a HTTP request from Node.JS, you could use [http.request](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest) or use another library like [request](https://github.com/request/request) helping you to code without complexities, here is an example using the [request](https://github.com/request/request) library:

```
var request = require('request');
var URL = 'http://www.google.com';

request(URL, function(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
    console.log(body);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers. I got the answer to the question using the library https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlhttprequest

Risto Novik, this is a simple example and of course i have to validate the fields!